# Web application not working in swarm mode while using traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, load-balancing, docker-swarm, traefik

**I'm trying to use Traefik to load-balance my web apps via docker swarm.
I have installed sample application like joomla in swarm mode behind traefik. Joomla works fine when the application is deployed on the same node as traefik (ie, manager), and I can access it through the browser by hitting the manager's node IP. But, if the service gets deployed on the worker node with no container in the manager node, while the service is up and running without any issue, but I am not able to see anything on the browser (hitting the manager or worker IP)

```
My traefik.toml file:

defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
loglevel = "INFO" 
sendAnonymousUsage = true 
[docker] 
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  exposedByDefault = false 
[api] 
  dashboard = true 
  entrypoint = "dashboard" 
[entryPoints] 
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80" 
  [entryPoints.dashboard] 
  address = ":8080" 
--------------------------------
```

---

```
My traefik.yml file: 
version: '3'
services: 
  traefik: 
    image: traefik:v1.7 # The official Traefik docker image
    restart: always 
    ports: 
      - 80:80     # The HTTP port 
      - 9090:8080 # The Web UI (enabled by --api) 
    labels: 
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.dpaas1.pune.cdac.in 
      - traefik.port=8080 
      - traefik.enable=true 
    volumes: 
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events 
      - ${PWD}/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml 
    deploy: 
      mode: replicated 
      replicas: 1 
      restart_policy: 
        condition: on-failure 
        max_attempts: 3 
      placement: 
        constraints: [node.role == manager] 
      update_config: 
        delay: 2s 
    networks: 
      - net 
networks: 
  net: 
    external: true
```

---

````
My joomla.yml file: 

version: '3' 
services: 
  joomla: 
    image: joomla 
    restart: always 
    links: 
      - joomladb:mysql
    volumes: 
      - joomla1-www:/var/www/html 
    deploy: 
      mode: replicated 
      replicas: 3 
      restart_policy: 
        condition: on-failure 
        max_attempts: 3 
      placement: 
        constraints: [node.role == manager] 
      update_config: 
        delay: 2s 
    labels: 
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:joomla1.dpaas1.pune.cdac.in 
      - traefik.port=80 
      - traefik.enable=true 
      - traefik.backend.loadbalancer.sticky=true 
    environment: 
      JOOMLA_DB_HOST: 10.208.26.162 
      JOOMLA_DB_PASSWORD: root 
    tty: true 
    networks: 
      - net 
networks: 
  net: 
    external: true
volumes:
  joomla1-www: 
_______________________
```_____________ **

My traefik Dashboard:
[![Traefik logs and dashboard][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcoGu.png
````

Comment: When you are running Joomla on the manager node are you sure you're hitting it via Traefik?  To do so you would need to be making a request with the hostname in your yml, ie. joomla1.dpaas1.pune.cdac.in.  Otherwise you wouldn't trigger the Traefik routing rule.  Definitely would like to see output of Traefik logs.  I think you may find you are missing the "traefik.docker.network=net" label.

Comment: @fifofonix I am able to access my application through joomla.dpaas1.pune.cdac.in . I have also tried with commenting out the traefik labels, then it's not working. Please help me with how can I get traefik logs

Comment: Recommend the following directives in your traefik.toml file `debug = true`, `logLevel = "DEBUG"`, and then do a `docker service logs <service_name>`.  You can also `docker exec <container_name> sh` and navigate to /var/logs and see any files that may be being updated there.

Comment: I have gone through traefik service logs, It has entries of me accessing joomla url through browser. @fifofonix

Comment: And what do the logs show when you switch to the non-working configuration?  Perhaps you can add any warnings and errors seen in the question.

Comment: By non-working configuration- I have hashed all the traefik labels and started the service on a particular port and it's working fine. And one more thing I want to highlight, I am able to see traefik service logs, but not joomla service logs. any leads

Comment: I get that it works when deployed as manager. My hope was that you could post logs created when it is deployed as worker and doesn’t work for you.

Comment: When deploying at the worker node, I am not able to see any respective log entry for that application. and again the service is up and running on another node.

Comment: And can you please comment if my traefik is configured correctly or not. I am using the above .yml and toml file. Please suggest if I should add or delete something.

Comment: The only thing I could spot when contrasting with prior Traefik 1.7 configs I have had is that you haven't declared network as traefik labels (one of the points I made on first comment).  However, I'm not super-confident that is your issue.  I do think a screenshot of dashboard and configuration Traefik thinks it has detected would be useful; which is why I suggested enabling dashboard.  If you can't provide any other info/diagnostics then I'm sorry I can't help.

Comment: I have added the dashboard and logs screen   https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcoGu.png

Comment: The issue is resolved. @fifofonix

Comment: Great.  Anything we can do to clean up this post here and help others facing a similar problem?

Comment: The problem was with the yml file. Labels should be placed as a sub part of deploy parameter to work in swarm mode.